# Runtime error '1004' while creating a pivot table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

I am trying to create a pivot table after copying the data from one workbook to another workbook.  Here is the code.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets.Add
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "PIVOT_RANGE", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14). _
        CreatePivotTable TableDestination:=ws.Name & "!R1C1", TableName:= _
        "PivotTable2", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14
```

I am seeing different pivot table name every time.  Sometimes it shows **PivotTable1** and Sometimes it shows **PivotTable2**.

I am also getting the following error message

**'Run-time error 1004':**

***The PivotTable field name is not valid. To create a PivotTable report, you must use data that is organized as a list with labeled columns.  If you are changing the name of a PivotTable field, you must type a new name for the field.***

I actually have the data from A1:X and all the columns have column headings, but still I am getting this error message.

Just wanted to know is there a way to get pivot table name through VBA instead of giving the table name in code (i.e. **TableName:= "PivotTable2"**) which is not the same most of the times.

Can someone please help me on this?

Comment: You can leave out the `Tablename` parameter altogether.

Comment: I'd recommend avoiding using Excel's default `PivotTableX` naming scheme and coming up with something more unique if you need to give it a name. You could use something simple like `MyPivotX` if you need to. I believe you're probably running into an issue with an already existing `PivotTable2`.